# Unity Unable to build app after adding admob plugin

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

Hi so i am trying to build my game app apk..
it was working earlier but now after i added the admob plugin i start to receive these error when building
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/tag/v3.6.3

```
Failed to compile resources with the following parameters:
-bootclasspath "D:/Android/sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -d "C:\Users\Eric\Documents\UnityProjects\Repos\HerderGame\HerderGame\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "android\support\v4\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\ads\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\ads\impl\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\base\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\clearcut\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\gass\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\tasks\R.java" "com\google\unity\ads\R.java" "com\Unity2D\Napmi\R.java"
warning: D:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar(java/lang/Object.class): major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
warning: D:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar(java/lang/AutoCloseable.class): major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
2 warnings

UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Another error

```
UnityException: Resource compilation failed!
Failed to recompile android resource files. See the Console for details.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.ShowErrDlgAndThrow (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.ShowErrDlgAndThrow (System.String title, System.String message)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.CompileResources (System.String stagingArea, System.String packageName, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidLibraries androidLibraries)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcessInternal (System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:316)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

last one

```
Error building Player: UnityException: Resource compilation failed!
Failed to recompile android resource files. See the Console for details.
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your java sdk is compatible/up to date with your current version of android sdks. For that matter check that android sdk v. 25 is up correct as well.

"D:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar(java/lang/Object.class): major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler." I would search into this error and the similar one it listed.

Comment: thanks! i now can compile my project :D  i just update my java sdk to the latest one 1.8

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue with my game.
So, i realized that was the Admob plugin.

Try to downgrad or update your googleads unity plugin.

The solution was for me was "DOWNGRADE
googleads-mobile-unity v7.0.0 to
googleads-mobile-unity v6.1.2

Cheers!